# how to convert two bytes into integer

Tags: integer, byte, bit

I'm trying to size of a BMP file in bytes, but i don't know how to read two (or n) bytes and convert it to int.
For example:

```
13 0B 00 00 = 2835 
46 04 00 00 = 1094
B6 51 01 00 = 86454
```

Comment: What language? Please specify

Answer (score 2):

You just need to multiply the individual bytes by 256 (equivalent to shifting left 8 bits). The only tricky part is that you need to know which order to multiply them in. That is called **endianness**. [Read more about endianness here.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)

```
intVal = ((B0 * 256 + B1) * 256 + B2) * 256 + B3
```

In your example, the bytes are stored in *little endian* form (*LSB* first), so converting the first first set of bytes goes like this:

```
(((0x00 * 256) + 0x00) * 256 + 0x0B) * 256 + 0x13
```

Comment: 0x13(19) 0x0B(11) => 19* 256 + 11 = 4875 not 2835  as I wish

Comment: wow, that is what i need, thanks for the link and the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

If the language you're working on supports shifting then try `intVal = buffer1 | buffer2 << 8`

For your case this will be:
`19 | 22 << 8` = 2835

Much simpler, brief and to the point.

Also see [Convert 2 bytes into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071458/convert-2-bytes-into-an-integer) for more details on a very similar scenario